# Datagrid not updating after data change

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have a WPF `DataGrid` bound to a `ObservableCollection` via `dg.ItemsSource = myCollection;`

The MyClass implements `INotifyPropertyChanged`. I have a calculated property which is calculated async.

The property is a SolidColorBrush bound to the color of the Text. After the value of the property changes the `DataGrid` does **not** update immediately, but it updates as soons as I select the line of the item of which the property changed it display the updated value.

What can I do to let the DataGrid update immediately? I can't use XAML binding for the ItemsSource.

Binding:

```
<DataGridTextColumn Foreground={Binding Path=MyBrushProperty} />
```

Code of the class:

```
public class MyClass : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
public SolidColorBrush MyBrushProperty {
   get {
      CalcMyBrush();
      return _myBrushProperty;
   }
  set{
   _myBrushProperty = value; 
   OnPropertyChanged("MyBrushProperty");
  }
}
private void CalcMyBrush(){
   //DoSomething that changes _myBrushProperty and takes some time and needs to run async and after that sets
   MyBrushProperty = somevalue;

}
}
```

Comment: Post relevant XAML code here.

Comment: @RohitVats basically Foreground={Binding Path=MyColorProperty}

Comment: Try specifying async in binding if it's evaluated asynchronously. `Foreground={Binding Path=MyColorProperty,IsAsync=True}`.

Comment: `I can't use XAML binding in this case` - What?

Comment: @HighCore Added Dummycode & Explained

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to rise PropertyChanged event for your calculated property after you got async result of calculation.

something like this

```
public SolidColorBrush MyBrushProperty{get{return myBrushProperty;}}
private void CalcMyBrush()
{
    var awaiter = YourAsyncCalculation.GetAwaiter();
    awaiter.OnComplited(()=>
    {
     myBrushProperty= (SolidColorBrush)awaiter.GetResult();
     OnPropertyChanged("MyBrushProperty"); 
    });
}
```

Comment: I changed it because of another suggestion. But I made sure that the PropertyChanged event is called after the value is changed. still no effect. I think the Problem is somewhere, when the DataGrid decides to update.

Comment: When you rise an enevt your grid do property get{} logic and just call async  method and it may be don't waiting for result; So i't better to  init calculation when incoming parameters are changed and make the reading of property easy

Comment: in WPF DataGrid desides to update value just on PropertyChangend event . It does'n need something else like in Winforms. And if you need to update entire collection it needs to rise PropertyChanged event on the  collection property of ViewModel

Answer (score 0):

Notice you cannot change UI items from different threads (read about STA Apartment State). The idea is that the creating thread is the single owner of the created item. 
For example, the following code is no good for two reasons:
1. The  NotifyOfPropertyChange("MyBrushProperty"); might be called before the task is calculatd.
2. And less obvious, the task content will result in an exception saying:

The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it.
There might be a few problems here.

Make sure you turn on all exception flags or explore the color property in _myBrushProperty

```
    public class ModuleBMainWindowViewModel : Screen , INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public ModuleBMainWindowViewModel()
    {
        _myBrushProperty = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.White);
        DisplayName = "ModuleB";
        CalcMyBrush();

    }
    private SolidColorBrush _myBrushProperty;
    public SolidColorBrush MyBrushProperty
    {
        get
        {
            return _myBrushProperty;
        }
        set
        {
            _myBrushProperty = value;
        }
    }
    private void CalcMyBrush()
    {
         Task.Run(() =>
        {
            //DoSomething that changes _myBrushProperty and takes some time and needs to run async and after that sets
            _myBrushProperty = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Blue);
        });

         NotifyOfPropertyChange("MyBrushProperty");
    }
}
```

Comment: this should be a comment.

Comment: I don't have the apropriate reputation for a comment yet but 10x for the heads up;

Comment: OP has already mentioned in question - `The class the ObservableCollection contains implements INotifyPropertyChanged`.

Comment: @MichaelLo I'm using INotifyPropertyChanged. The line is getting updated, but just as I select it and not as the value really changes.

Comment: Try to get the OnPropertyChanged("MyBrushProperty") code from CalcMyBrush() and place it inside the "get { .. }"

Comment: @MichaelLo Sorry I do not understand what you mean. If I place the OnPropertyChanged in the get accessor it would actually be a infinitive loop.

Comment: @Campl3r your right! I ment to write the set accessor. The important thing I want you to try is calling the property changed from the UI thread, which means you cannot place it inside the async method.

Comment: It's hard to say where is the correct place to raise the event, is there more than one call to the async function? should it not be place it ctor ?